# Show Sub Menu on click and not hover

Tags: menus, sub-menu

I have a menu in which I am trying to get the sub menu to appear on click as opposed to hover.  I have the hover styles set and working so when I hover the sub-nav appears as a block element.  Not having any luck removing the hover and trying to add click event.  If the parent link is clicked the page just refreshes.

```
const subMenuLink = document.querySelector(".main-nav .menu .menu-item-has-children");
const subMenu = document.querySelector(".main-nav .menu .menu-item-has-children ul");

subMenuLink.addEventListener("click", toggleMenu);

function toggleMenu() {
  if (subMenu.classList.contains("visible")) {
    subMenu.classList.remove("visible");
  } else {
    subMenu.classList.add("visible");
  }
}
```

I feel like this is on track...but not so yet!  Any suggestions please, thank you

Comment: We need to see the CSS and the HTML before we can help you fix your error.

Answer (score 0):

This will add new classes to your menus triggered by click event. tell the default that you wish to not hover to have css of `li:hover {display:none;}`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.nav-menu .menu-item-has-children').on("click", function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            if($(this).is("li")){
                if($(this).hasClass('opened')){
                    $(this).addClass('closed');
                }else{$(this).removeClass('closed');}
                $(this).siblings().children('.sub-menu').removeClass('visible');
                $(this).siblings().removeClass('current-menu-parent opened');
                $(this).toggleClass('current-menu-parent opened');
                $(this).children('.sub-menu').toggleClass('visible');
            }
            else{
                if($(this).parent().hasClass('opened')){
                    $(this).parent().addClass('closed');
                }else{$(this).parent().removeClass('closed');}
                $(this).parent().siblings().children('.sub-menu').removeClass('visible');
                $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('current-menu-parent');
                $(this).parent().children('.sub-menu').toggleClass('visible');
                $(this).parent().toggleClass('current-menu-parent opened');
            }
    });
```